# What is difference between angular compiler and core version?

Tags: angular

in the package.json angular core version is ^6 , but when i command npm install , npm generates the warning below.

npm WARN @angular/compiler@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

where does the angular compiler 2.2.4 come from ? because i defined angular core and compiler version as ^6

my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^1.0.0",
    "@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-popper": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular2-promise-buttons": "^2.1.1",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-auto-complete": "^3.0.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.1.9",
    "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.4.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.28.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.12.13",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
```

Comment: Maybe it comes from some other dependencies you have in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

Are you upgrading Angular to v6? maybe you need use:

```
ng update
```

You can upgrade all angular packages to desired version. [Check docs](https://angular.io/cli/update)